# Python: For loop problem

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a simple for loop problem, when i run the code below it prints out series of 'blue green' sequences then a series of 'green' sequences. I want the output to be; if row[4] is equal to 1 to print blue else print green.

```
 for row in rows:
        for i in `row[4]`:
            if i ==`1`:
                print 'blue '
            else:
                print 'green '
```

Any help would be grateful

thanks

Yas

Comment: that doesn't seem like a valid python code. also, what is `rows`?

Comment: do you mean the contents of row at index 4 ( the fifth element ) is == 1 print blue else print green, or do you want to print blue on every forth line else print green?

Comment: Is rows 1 or 2 dimensional list?

Comment: Homework?  If so, please label it as [homework].

Comment: I don't think you're using the backticks correctly (do you really want the `repr` of `row[4]`?).  Is that a literal cut and paste of your code or did you edit it?

Comment: I think the backticks are a format error. He maybe marked it as code.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(rows)):
  if rows[i] == '1':
    print "blue"
  else:
    print "green"
```

Or, since you don't actually seem to care about the index, you can of course do it more cleanly:

```
for r in rows:
  if r == "1":
    print "blue"
  else:
    print "green"
```

Comment: why not doing `for row in rows` and testing the value of row ?

Comment: @LB: Um ... Because I was being a bit literal-minded, I guess. It happens. I'll edit, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the `enumerate()` function will iterate and give you the index as well as the value:

```
for i, v in enumerate(rows):
    if i == 4:
        print "blue"
    else:
        print "green"
```

if you want to print blue on every fourth line else green do this:

```
for i, v in enumerate(rows):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        print "blue"
    else:
        print "green"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if rows[4] == 1:
    print 'blue'
else:
    print 'green'
```